# Display/Hide cell in table using Birt report

Tags: eclipse, grid, birt

I Have two cell in one row.
I want to show and hide based on condition.
For cell visiblity expression option not showing this is showing only for text/label.

In the script I am adding

```
   if(params["chk"].value == "both"){
      this.getStyle().display = "none";}
```

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot hide a cell. This wouldn't make sense. You can hide the content inside a cell, or you can hide whole rows or columns.